# Android интеграция SDK + NDK

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-ndk, c++, java

Есть задачка написать xml парсер для андроида, используя уже готовый класс на с++. Время идет, а я не понимаю, как использовать из java класс на с++, так, чтобы в нем сохранялись данные.
В принципе я умею работать с нативными функциями. Но с классом пока не умею.

Пока писал вопрос, подумал, что из джавы можно вызывать какой-нибудь нативный Open() возвращающий идентификатор, и работать через него. Типа как с файлами. А в библиотеке под этим идентификатором будет храниться с++ класс.

Хм, уже вполне рабочая идея. Но может быть есть решение поизящнее?

Answer (score 1):

Я делю так.
В java-классе завожу поле для хранения нативных данных:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
public class MyJavaClass {
  static {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // для обхода ошибки с NewDirectByteBuffer
    ByteBuffer dummy = ByteBuffer.allocate(0); dummy = null;
    System.loadLibrary("<МойJNIМодуль>");
  }
  private ByteBuffer jnidata; // указывает на нативные данные
  private pdfPage() {} // запрет прямого вызова, создавать через native - функцию
...
```

В С++. Инициализация ссылок для доступа к java-классу:

```
jclass class_id=(jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass(javaclassname));
jfieldID field_id=env->GetFieldID(class_id, "jnidata", "Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;");
jmethodID init_id=env->GetMethodID(class_id,"<init>","()V");
```

NewGlobalRef нужно если вы хотите сохранить class_id между вызовами  в глобальной переменной.

Создание java-объекта:

```
jobject _this=env->NewObject(class_id, init_id);
```

Cвязать данные с java-объектом (data указывает на данные в C++):

```
void set_data(JNIEnv * env, jobject _this, data_t * data) { 
    env->SetObjectField(_this, field_id, ( data? env->NewDirectByteBuffer(data, sizeof *data) : 0 ));
}
```

Получить ссылку на свои данные

```
data_t * get_data(JNIEnv * env, jobject _this) {
    jobject obj=env->GetObjectField(_this, field_id);
    return obj? (data_t*) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(obj) : 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Пока реализовал свой вариант. Вышло просто офигенно. Как отпустит попробую разобраться с вашим.